# ScrollViewer is disabling virtualization thus causing slow performance in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

When I populate a `ListView` with 10000 rows of data, it is takes around 1 minute to launch the dialog. If I understand correctly, it is happening because `ScrollViewer` is turning off the virtualization of `ListView` (child). If I remove `ScrollViewer`, the dialog gets launched within 5 second.

**My problem is I don't want to remove `ScrollViewer` and virtualization should work for `ListView`.**

```
<Grid>
    <!--if we remove this scrollviewer then performance will drastically improve-->
     <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ListView Name="variablelist" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  ItemsSource="{Binding VariableList}" 
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" IsEnabled="{Binding ListViewVariablesIsEnabled}" 
                  SelectionMode="Single" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
                  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Margin="0,26,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                  KeyDown="variablelist_KeyDown">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding VariableNameWidth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{x:Static p:Resources.listviewColumnName}" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="Name" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn  Width="{Binding VariableScopeWidth, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
                      <GridViewColumnHeader Content="{x:Static p:Resources.listviewColumnScope}" Command="{Binding SortCommand}" CommandParameter="Scope" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"/>
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Scope}" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" ToolTip="{Binding Path=Scope}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>                           
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

From the code mentioned below based on the type of tab, Usercontrol mentioned above containing Scrolllviewer and Listview is getting launched. I have used Scrollviewer to scroll in case of usercontrol Zoom.

```
<Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition MaxHeight="20"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" 
                                ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" />
                </Grid.LayoutTransform>               
                <TextBlock Name="TitleBar" Text="{Binding Title}" ></TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <TabControl x:Name="pTAB" Grid.Row="1"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding TabItems}" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
                <TabControl.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Bottom"/>                       
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <Border Name="Border"
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                                            <TextBlock x:Name="TitleContent"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                                                   Text="{TemplateBinding Header}">
                                            </TextBlock>
                                        </Border>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </TabControl.Resources>
            </TabControl>
        </Grid>

        <Slider x:Name="ZoomSlider" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" 
                Minimum="1.0" Maximum="2.0" LargeChange="0.25" SmallChange="0.01"  Value="1.0" Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Grid>
```

**Already tried things:**

```
 <ListView Name="variablelist" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"  ItemsSource="{Binding VariableList}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}" IsEnabled="{Binding ListViewVariablesIsEnabled}" 
         SelectionMode="Single" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" 
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Margin="0,26,0,10" Grid.RowSpan="2" 
         KeyDown="variablelist_KeyDown" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
  VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
 ......
</ListView>
```

Comment: Why do you have that outer ScrollViewer in the first place? ListView already supports scrolling by default, and of course with virtualization.

Comment: Yes I know listview supports scrolling I am using outer  scrollviewer for scrolling user control in case of zoom

Comment: Which UserControl? There is nothing but a ListView inside the ScrollViewer.

Comment: This code is present inside a user control I have not mentioned the whole code because of copyright. Inside scrollviewer tag I have other UI elements as well. That's why I don't want to remove scrollviewer. Is there any other way to enable virtualization in listview without removing scrollviewer.

Comment: you might need to set the height so that it knows how to calculate the virtualization

Comment: Thank you very much @Jonatha Alfaro setting up Maxheight inside constructor worked for me. Previously i was setting up the Maxheight inside SizechangedEvent. thats why while loading it was not working. And i have used VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True"
  VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" with Listview  in Xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting up Maxheight of Listview inside constructor worked for me. Previously i was setting up the Maxheight inside SizechangedEvent,thats why while loading it was not working and causing performance issue. And i have also used VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" with Listview. So moral of the story is you can Manually enable virtualization in ListView present inside Scrollviewer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do any of that. ListView supports scrolling and virtualization by default.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding BigList}">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>

public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public IEnumerable<string> BigList { get; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++)
            list.Add(i.ToString());
        BigList = list;
    }
}
```

This will load almost instantly.

Comment: Yes I know listview supports scrolling I am using outer  scrollviewer for scrolling user control in case of zoom I have not mentioned the whole code. Inside scrollviewer tag I have other UI elements as well. That's why I don't want to remove scrollviewer. Is there any other way to enable virtualization in listview without removing scrollviewer.

Comment: Your ListView is in ScrollViewer so it will grow as much as it needs. The virtualization of the outer container will not apply to the ListView.

Comment: if i am getting you right you mean to say outer scrollviewer is not disabling listview virtualization. check this link http://harishasanblog.blogspot.com/2011/02/scrollviewer-causing-slow-performance.html

Comment: The arcticle explains it very nicely. You placed your grid inside the ScrollViewer so ListView can grow as much as it needs and it will never utilize it's own scroll viewer therefore no virtualization will take place.

Comment: Can you show the other controls and explain what you mean by zooming. Maybe there is another approach on the layout you are missing.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the code you are asking for. I am using slider for zooming and that's why i am using Scrollviewer to scroll in case of zoom.